# Devemos indicar fonte das wiki de tags quando ela vem da tag do SO em inglês?

Tags: debate, edição, wikis-de-tags

Até agora a maior parte dos textos das wikis das tags daqui vem das wikis das tags do SO em inglês. Sei bem disso porque fiz a maioria. Ninguém tem colocado a fonte, nesses casos, ela é necessária quando vem de outros sites, como a Wikipedia, por exemplo.

Acho que não foi debatido esse assunto e achei que estava implícito.

Outros sites da rede em inglês costumam pegar o texto das wikis de tags em sites da rede, principalmente o SO sem citar a fonte.

Isso deve ocorrer ou podemos considerar que a fonte é o próprio site e a citação não é necessária?

Seria bom citar no comentário apenas? Ou nem isso é necessário?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se a fonte é uma tradução de outro site da SE, a citação é desnecessária e seria equivalente a ter sido escrito por nós. Até porque futuras edições na tag vão alterar levemente o texto dela, até chegar a um ponto que se tornará substancialmente diferente. Até quando manter a citação nesse caso? Não faz muito sentido.

> Citações de fontes externas devem ser claramente citações (marcadas assim) para evitar que sejam alteradas, e com fonte.

O ideal é que o corpo principal seja escrito pela comunidade, sem uma fonte certa. E que citações nesse formato não sejam tão comuns.

Comment: Tenho minhas dúvidas. Mesmo que com o tempo modifiquemos bastante a tradução, a referência ao original (talvez até a uma revisão específica do original) ainda seria útil como referência (não citação). E tem certeza que "externo" quer dizer externo à rede, e não ao site? Vamos ver se o Gabe coloca a posição oficial da SE quanto a isso.

Answer (score 2):

eIndependente do conteúdo tornar-se substancialmente diferente com o tempo, acredito que é sempre bom manter as fontes de referências.

Acho que todas as respostas, se possível, poderiam manter esse padrão de informar as fontes.

Nenhum livro ou enciclopédia que conheço, deixa de citar fontes relevantes do seu conteúdo.

As fontes tornam o conteúdo mais rico pois quem lê pode consultá-las diretamente e aprofundar-se nas pesquisas.